# Rails removes target="_blank"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple blog application on rails 4.1.4 that allows users to create posts. Whenever a user adds a link in their post, the target="_blank" tag is removed by rails. For example:

User inputs:

```
<a href="www.google.com" target="_blank">Google</a>
```

When viewing source of the created post:

```
<a href="www.google.com">Google</a>
```

is shown.

Am I missing something obvious here? Why is the target attribute being removed by rails?

Comment: What is your rails code?

Comment: Are you sanitizing the HTML that comes from user input?  Perhaps it's stripping out the target attribute.

Answer (score 15):

Rails sanitizes output by default, and the target attribute is one of the attributes that gets stripped out by default.  You can white list the target attribute with something like:

`<%= sanitize html.body, attributes: %w(href target) %>`

More info here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html