# simple_format is stripping out target _blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
= simple_format(styled_text_for_tagged_text(block.text_block.body, article))
```

This appears to be stripping attributes like `target="_blank"` out of my link. I can't use `auto_link`. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A much better way to do this is to turn off the sanitizer in the simple_format method, and call sanitize on the contents yourself, where you can specify not to strip the target attributes out.

```
= simple_format(sanitize(body, attributes: ["href", "target"]), {}, sanitize: false)
```

Then you get the benefits of both simple_format and sanitize.

Ref [Rails removes target="_blank"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786876/rails-removes-target-blank)

Answer (score 0):

Not sanitizing the output ended up being the answer:

```
= simple_format(styled_text_for_tagged_text(block.text_block.body, article), {}, :sanitize => false)
```